# Linq Many to many in Entity Framework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have classes for building many to many relationships.

```
public class Chat 
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserChat> UserChats { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserChat
{
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public Guid ChatId { get; set; }
    public Chat Chat { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{        
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserChat> UserChats { get; set; }       
}
```

For example, I have a `user1` and `user2`

1. I need to Select chats for `user1` where chat contains a `user2`
2. I need to select chat for `user1` where chat contains a `user2` and not contains another users (like one chat contains only 2 participants)

   How I can do this in EF Core via one request to DB?

Comment: Shouldn't `UserId` be on `ApplicationUser`?

Comment: @devNull, yes, applicationUser contains UserId

Comment: for number one: first, get the `UserId` for your `user1` and `user2` into a list of string - `userIdList`, then `dbContext.Chat.Where(x => x.UserChats.Any(y => userIdList.Contains(y.UserId)))`. the reason i suggest using the user id is to avoid confusion when you fetch the query result on different database context.

Comment: Do you need to fetch both **1** and **2** in one request or one request per case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is acceptable to perform 2 queries to database to get data for both cases you can use following queries

```
//chats that contain user1 and user2
var chats1 = context
    .Chats
    .Where(c => c.UserChats.Any(u => u.UserId == userId1))
    .Where(c => c.UserChats.Any(u => u.UserId == userId2))
    .ToList();

//chats that contain user1 and user2 and they are only users in chat
var chats2 = context
    .Chats
    .Where(c => c.UserChats.Any(u => u.UserId == userId1))
    .Where(c => c.UserChats.Any(u => u.UserId == userId2))
    .Where(c => c.UserChats.Count() == 2)
    .ToList();
```

If you want to retrieve all data in 1 request you can declare new class which holds needed information about chat

```
public class ChatDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public int UserCount { get; set; }
}
```

and perform following request

```
var chats = context
    .Chats
    .Where(c => c.UserChats.Any(u => u.UserId == userId1))
    .Where(c => c.UserChats.Any(u => u.UserId == userId2))
    .Select(c => new ChatDto
    {
        Id = c.Id,
        UserCount = c.UserChats.Count()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Therefore you will have chats that contain *user1* and *user2* and total count of users in chat.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var chats = user1.UserChats.Select(uc => uc.ChatId).Distinct();
 var result1 = context.ApplicationUserChat
       .Where(a => a.UserId == user2.Id && chats.Contains(a.ChatId))
       .Select(a => a.Chat)
       .ToList();
 var result2 = results1.Except(context.ApplicationUserChat
       .Where(a => a.UserId != user2.Id 
                   && a.UserId != user2.Id 
                   && chats.Contains(a.ChatId))
       .Select(a => a.Chat)
       .Distinct())
       .ToList();
```

//loading... short version using/if you already have the users lists:

```
 var result1 = user1.UserChat.Intersect(user2.UserChats);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it's can help me but probably we have a variant doing this via one request, i think it's a bad for performance execute 3 request to DB